# is the ordering of std::type_index stable?

Tags: c++

Can the ordering of std::type_index be relied on to be stable over

- multiple invocations of the same executable file
- multiple invocations of the different executable file with the number and names of classes not changed
- even if some of these classes are defined in an unnamed namespace

I know that `std::type_info` does not guarantee such thing?
Does `std::type_index`?
Should one rather use `std::type_info::name()` for the ordering?

Comment: `std::type_info::name()` is even worse as it also doesn't guarantee consistency between invocations, but different types can have the same name : "No guarantees are given; in particular, the returned string can be identical for several types and change between invocations of the same program."

Comment: It is meaningless to ask whether two classes in two different programs are "the same class". The relation of being the same class is only defined within a program. The standard does not define "executable file" at all, or what are "different executions of the same program by the same implementation". Is gcc 13.0 on my machine the same implementation as gcc 13.0 on your machine? is gcc 13.0 on my machine yesterday the same implementation as gcc 13.0 on my machine today, after a minor OS update?(Needless to say, with different implementations the order may differ).

Answer (score 7):

`type_info`'s comparison operators [are based on](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/type.index.members) `type_index::before`'s behavior. And the standard specifically states that `before` [provides no guarantees outside of the execution of a single program](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/type.info#1):

> The names, encoding rule, and collating sequence for types are all unspecified and may differ between programs.